# jQuery Variables with this

Tags: jquery, variables

I was trying to apply a variable for code that I'm reusing (the activechange), but I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way to define these. I also didn't know how I could add the .fadeIn()"..." code as a variable also by making my own function.

```
$(function () {
    var activechange = $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#video-left').mouseover(function () {
        activechange;
        $('#product-left').fadeIn().addClass('active').siblings('.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#video-center').mouseover(function () {
        activechange;
        $('#product-center').fadeIn().addClass('active').siblings('.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#video-right').mouseover(function () {
        activechange;
        $('#product-right').fadeIn().addClass('active').siblings('.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to apply the variable to? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I just have repeating code that I would like to assign to a variable, but it's not working for me. (the activechange variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function

```
var activechange = function (){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
}
```

Usage

```
activechange.apply(this);
```

### OR

```
var activechange = function (obj){
    $(obj).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
}
```

Usage

```
activechange(this);
```

Comment: You might want to provide the IIFE example too since OP's function is in that form.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it into function:

```
function blah(elem) {
    elem.addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');

}

$('#video-left').mouseover(  function(){                                 
    blah($(this))
});
```